# SQL - products model

Tags: sql, postgresql

### 1.

**Question:** [SQL statement] How much costs 18 grams of product called A?

**Answer:** 135 (7.50 * 18) because 1 costs 10 but price from quantity of 10 is 7.50

### 2.

**Or:** help me rewrite this model more efficient

products table [quanity of 1]

```
id | name | price | unit
1  | A    | 10    | g 
2  | B    | 15    | g
```

sales table

```
id | product_id | price | quanity
1  | 1          | 7.50  | 10
2  | 1          | 7     | 20
3  | 2          | 12.50 | 10
```

or do you have any idea how to build this model differently?

Comment: Are you asking how to write that SQL statement or how to effectively model your data? Which price are you after? The price that you sold it at in your `Sales` table or the price that it currently is being sold for in your `products` table? Please share your desired results and clarify your question.

Comment: @JNevill I rewrote my question

Comment: I have seen this done with a separate table called "PriceLevel" which would relate to the Products table, and would contain the break points for the quantities where the price is reduced. Unless that's what you intend for the Sales table itself. This way you can do a JOIN to calculate the price break points instead of nesting queries or doing CASE statements for the calculation.

Comment: Are you using 7.50 because they are buying between 10 and 20 of product_id 1?

Comment: @JNevill Yes. [10, 20] (cause from 20 price is changing)

Comment: @JNevill that's how I'm understanding it. A bit odd to call the table "Sales" as one would think that would have transactional sales data (i.e. customer purchases). But conceptually it's a "pricing levels" table.

Comment: @JNevill Can you please create an answer with solution? I think you can solve my issue.

Comment: Why do you have price in the products table? Shouldn't you add another line in "Sales" where ID = 1, product_id = 1, price = 10 and quantity = 0? This is definitely not normalized as is.

Comment: Talking to the Schema portion of the question, I would remove "Quantity" form the `sales` table and instead of `min_qty` and `max_qty`. Then the SQL becomes trivial: `SELECT 18*price FROM sales WHERE 18 between min_qty and max_qty;` As it's set up now you will need to employ window functions, or `SELECT TOP 1... ORDER BY` subquery or other expensive nonsense.

Comment: @JNevill Can you please answer w/ solution?

Answer (score -3):

Try this query you need:

```
 SELECT S.PRICE*1.8 FROM SALES S 
    INNER JOIN PRODUCTS P 
    ON P.ID=S.PRODUCT_ID 
    WHERE P.NAME='A'
```

Comment: Your query is incorrect. It is poorly formatted (use the code button to format code). It also comes with no supporting information. Please fix or delete.